# Extract rows from csv file using regex substring?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this (obviously < anystring > means just that).

```
<anystring>tony_UPearly_start,1,2,3
<anystring>tony_UPlate_start,4,5,6
<anystring>tony_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9
<anystring>jane_UPearly_start,1,2,3
<anystring>jane_UPlate_start,4,5,6
<anystring>jane_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9
```

I am trying to  extract rows  UPanystring (rows 3 and 6 in this example) using negative look forward to exclude rows 1,2 and 4,5

```
import re
import csv

search = re.compile(r'.*_UP(?!early|late)')
output = []

with open('test.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvfile:
        if row[0] == search:
            output.append(row)

print(output)

>>>[]
```

when I am after

```
print (output)

[<anystring>tony_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9, <anystring>jane_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9]
```

The regex search works when I test on a regex platform but not in python?

Thanks for the comments: the search code now looks like

```
search = re.compile(r'^.*?_UP(?!early|late).*$')
output = []

with open('test.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvfile:
        search.search(row[0]) # it think this needs and if=true but it won't accept a boolean here?
        output.append(row)
```

This now returns all rows (ie filters nothing whereas before it filtered everything)

Comment: You're not using your regex properly - to search use `search.search(row[0])` . Read more on [`Pattern.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search).

Comment: Thanks both - these both change the output in both cases I now have all rows in the output list?

Comment: How does your whole `if ...` statement look now?

Comment: Thanks I think Im struggling with the .search syntax. have added to the original question.

Comment: Use `if not search.search(row[0]): ...` to pass only the lines that do not match your pattern.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.  Its a negative look forward so I just needed `if` since `if not` passed the lines I wasn't after.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a list of rows that contain `_UP` not followed with `early` or `late`.

The pattern should look like

```
search = re.compile(r'_UP(?!early|late)')
```

You do not need any `^`, `.*`, etc. because when you use `re.search`, you are looking for a pattern match anywhere inside a string.

Then, all you need is to test the row for the regex match:

```
if search.search(row):
    output.append(row)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aLpRP0):

```
import re

csvfile="""<anystring>tony_UPearly_start,1,2,3
<anystring>tony_UPlate_start,4,5,6
<anystring>tony_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9
<anystring>jane_UPearly_start,1,2,3
<anystring>jane_UPlate_start,4,5,6
<anystring>jane_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9""".splitlines()

search = re.compile(r'_UP(?!early|late)')
output = []

for row in csvfile:
    if search.search(row):
        output.append(row)

print(output)
```

And the output is your expected list:

```
['<anystring>tony_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9', '<anystring>jane_UP<anystring>_start,7,8,9']
```